# Trigger specific element in array then iterating through other array

Tags: javascript, angular

I've got this situation, where I have array of `chronicles` that contain array of photos I am displaying in the carousel slider. When clicking on arrows I want slider to show next photo. It works fine, however **ALL** of the sliders move to right/left on the click, while only the one I'm clicking on should move. How could I solve that?

Here's my code:

```
index = 0;
// if a current image is the same as requested image
isActive(index) {
  return this.index === index;
}

// show prev image
showPrev(photos: Photo[], chronicle: Chronicle, id: number) {
  if (photos[id].fkChronicle === chronicle.id) {
    id = (id > 0) ? --id : photos.length - 1;
  }
}

// show next image
showNext(photos: Photo[], chronicle: Chronicle, id: number) {
  if (photos[id].fkChronicle === chronicle.id) {
    this.index = (this.index < photos.length - 1) ? ++this.index : 0;
  }
}

// show a certain image
showPhoto(index) {
  this.index = index;
}
```

..

```
<div *ngIf="chronicles">
  <div *ngFor="let c of chronicles">
    {{c.title}} {{c.date | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
    <div class="container slider">
      {{!isActive(i)}}
      <!-- enumerate all photos -->
      <div *ngFor="let photo of c.photos; let i = index">
        <img class="slide materialboxed" (click)="showPhoto(i)" [hidden]="!isActive(i)" (change)="isActive(i)" src="../../../assets/chronicles/{{photo.title}}" />
        <!-- prev / next controls -->
        <a class="arrow prev" (click)="showPrev(c.photos, c, i)"><i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_left</i></a>
        <a class="arrow next" (click)="showNext(c.photos, c, i)"><i class="material-icons">navigate_next</i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't have working sample online, but I used this as a reference: https://codepen.io/leunicornsea/pen/oOOdpM (I re-did it in angular 7)

Comment: code in codepen is angular js and posted code is Angular

Comment: I would assume this happens because every single slideshow uses the same array of photos with the same index to track them. It may be better off to isolate each slideshow and its respective data in it's own component/directive.

Comment: You need a separate index for each chronicle. So the index could be a member of   `Chronicle`. Or an array of the same size as `chronicles`. You can't use a single index for all.